# How to consume Json data from asp.net webservice with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, web-services

Once upon a time, there was a project on which a person was working. This project had a master page and a content page. The content page had a drop-down list and two text boxes. However, when the person selected any product name from the drop-down list, how curious, it's `totalQuantity` and `pricePerItem` values did not appear in the text boxes! He was trying to write web service code and javascript code for this project, but unfortunately it did not do what he had in mind it should and would do. Therefore, he is requesting your help.

```
 public class QuantityAndPrice
{
    public string totalQuantity { get; set; }
    public string pricePerItem { get; set; }
}
```

> webservice code

```
  public class QuantityAndPriceService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void GetQuantityAndPrice(string productName)
    {
        QuantityAndPrice quantityAndpriceObject = new QuantityAndPrice();

        string connect_string = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connect_string);
        string query = "select totalQuantity,pricePerItem from smart_shop.inventory where name='" + productName + "';";
        MySqlCommand  cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



        while (reader.Read())
        {
            quantityAndpriceObject.totalQuantity = reader.GetString("totalQuantity");
            quantityAndpriceObject.pricePerItem = reader.GetString("pricePerItem");
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
       Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(quantityAndpriceObject));


    }
}
```

> javascript

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#productNameDDL').change(function () {

                var pName = $('#productNameDDL').val();

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'QuantityAndPriceService.asmx/GetQuantityAndPrice',
                    data: { productName: pName },
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#tbxAvailableQuantity').val(data.totalQuantity);
                        $('#tbxPricePerItem').val(data.pricePerItem);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });


    </script>
```

> and here aspx code

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                         <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Available Qty</h6>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAvailableQuantity" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                         <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Price/Item</h6>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPricePerItem" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                </div> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                         <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales Qty</h6>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="tbxSalesQtuantity" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                         <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Price</h6>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalPrice" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>                 

            </div>




  <asp:DropDownList ID="productNameDDL" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: data.d contains all the objects in asp.net web form

Answer (score 0):

1. Web service class should have
   [ScriptService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
   attribute.
2. Web service method should have    [ScriptMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
   attribute to specify the `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json`.
3. In java script `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and     `dataType: 'json'` should be specified.
4. The results in success part of ajax call is contained in `d` e.g.    like this `data.d.totalQuantity`.
5. Data in ajax call should be stringified e.g. like this `data:JSON.stringify({ productName: pName })`

---

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class QuantityAndPriceService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public QuantityAndPrice GetQuantityAndPrice(string productName)
    {
        QuantityAndPrice quantityAndpriceObject = new QuantityAndPrice
        {
            totalQuantity = "totalQuantityValue",
            pricePerItem = "pricePerItemValue"
        };
        return quantityAndpriceObject;
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'QuantityAndPriceService.asmx/GetQuantityAndPrice',
    data: JSON.stringify({ productName: pName }),
    method: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#tbxAvailableQuantity').val(data.d.totalQuantity);
        $('#tbxPricePerItem').val(data.d.pricePerItem);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what i'm missing still not working but for checking when a run QuantityAndPriceService.asmx return expected value but don't appear in textboxes

Comment: There was a question on which a person was working hard. However when the person submited his answer, how curious, it was still not working. Maybe this person could ask, what exactly was not working?

Comment: I use this code in my project but not working....i'm sorry to say...it appears json data but don't show in textboxes

Comment: I can't say why this is not working, but [here on my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4kyrclb0vaa6xe5/AACTix8GdEDV2Qivmg61ihzja?dl=0) you can find a complete sample solution where I have tested this problem. For me it works that way. HTH